# How add a message optional parts in the ASN.1 generated C codes

Tags: c, asn.1

I have used the C code from [libosmo-asn1-map](http://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-map/) to obtain an implementation of the GSM_MAP protocol. Then I try to encode a
"*Send authentication Info*" message. As mentioned in the [3GPP TS 29.002](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/129000_129099/129002/10.02.00_60/ts_129002v100200p.pdf), this message contains some mandatory parts (e.g. 'imsi') and some optional parts (e.g. 'requestingNodeType').

```
/* SendAuthenticationInfoArg */
typedef struct SendAuthenticationInfoArg {
    IMSI_t   imsi;
    NumberOfRequestedVectors_t   numberOfRequestedVectors;
    NULL_t  *segmentationProhibited /* OPTIONAL */;
    NULL_t  *immediateResponsePreferred /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct Re_synchronisationInfo   *re_synchronisationInfo /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct ExtensionContainer   *extensionContainer /* OPTIONAL */;
    /*
     * This type is extensible,
     * possible extensions are below.
     */
    RequestingNodeType_t    *requestingNodeType /* OPTIONAL */;
    PLMN_Id_t   *requestingPLMN_Id  /* OPTIONAL */;
    NumberOfRequestedVectors_t  *numberOfRequestedAdditional_Vectors    /* OPTIONAL */;
    NULL_t  *additionalVectorsAreForEPS /* OPTIONAL */;

    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} SendAuthenticationInfoArg_t;
```

I used the following C code which was inspired from [osmo-tcap-map](https://git.osmocom.org/osmo-tcap-map/tree/test/gprs_update.c) project.

```
SendAuthenticationInfoArg_t ula;
memset(&ula, 0, sizeof(ula));

ASN1Common::OCTET_STRING_fromRevVal(&ula.imsi, 202015604083166);
ula.requestingNodeType = 0;
ula.numberOfRequestedVectors = 5;    
xer_fprint(stdout, &asn_DEF_SendAuthenticationInfoArg, &ula);
```

But there is no optional part in the XER output, while '*requestingNodeType*' has been initialized:

```
<SendAuthenticationInfoArg>
    <imsi>02 02 51 06 04 38 61 F6</imsi>
    <numberOfRequestedVectors>5</numberOfRequestedVectors>
</SendAuthenticationInfoArg>
```

How can I enable the optional parts (i.e. add 'requestingNodeType' to the message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `requestingNodeType` and `numberOfRequestedVectors` are pointers

```
RequestingNodeType_t    *requestingNodeType /* OPTIONAL */;
PLMN_Id_t   *requestingPLMN_Id  /* OPTIONAL */;
NumberOfRequestedVectors_t  *numberOfRequestedAdditional_Vectors    /* OPTIONAL */;
NULL_t  *additionalVectorsAreForEPS /* OPTIONAL */;
```

so you first need to allocate them, it should be something like

```
ula.requestingNodeType = malloc(sizeof(RequestingNodeType_t));
asn_long2INTEGER(ula.requestingNodeType, RequestingNodeType_vlr);
```

The `RequestingNodeType_t` is typedef'd as `ENUMERATED_t` that is typedef'd as `INTEGER_t` and that's why we can't assigned the value directly but using the `asn_long2INTEGER`

```
ula.numberOfRequestedVectors = malloc(sizeof(NumberOfRequestedVectors_t));
*ula.numberOfRequestedVectors = 5;
```

The `NumberOfRequestedVectors_t` is typedef'd as `long` so here we could assign the value directly